# How to handle invalid date in mvc

Tags: c#, validation, datetime, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I have a textbox for date of birth on the index page. I have to validate user to enter complete date format(`mm/dd/yyyy`), but its allowing to post 03/12(mm/dd) without year and in c# side it converted to 03/12/2015.

My requirement is to validate user to enter complete date format.
I used data annotation but that also not handling (mm/dd) as invalid date.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Search.DOB, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
```

Comment: what you had tried so far ?

Comment: Where is the code? How are you doing validation on the client side? `TextBoxFor` won't create any validation scripts, it will simply display and bind a Textbox. Generating validation scripts is the job of `EditFor`.

Comment: From @Ecorry: Maybe you could use regular expression in javascript, when fucusout event be triggered!

Comment: Or just use a calendar box, then on post validate the value, against what is stored in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use regular expression in javascript,
when fucusout event be triggered!

or solve the problem by following

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: I used these things but nothing is working. I have no any option to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [html5 form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) it works without javascript.
For example:

```
<input type="text"
       name="DOB"
       placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"
       title="MM/dd/yyyy"
       required
       pattern="^([1-9]|1[0-2])/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])/\d{4}$" />
```